# best newline type to be used in txt files that works on all androids

Tags: android

am creating an android ap mainly js/html/css and it will be manipulating  txt files so am confused which one to use as newline between

```
\n and \r\n
```

although both seems to work on my test phone but which one will work on all androids

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which one will work on all androids

Android is linux based so as per the environment `\n` would be fine